# fetch data from excel to Datatable flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Excel file I would like to fetch so that I can display it in a DataTable. Now imagine the data below is inside my Excel file:

```
final allUsers = <User>[
  User(firstName: 'Emma', lastName: 'Field', age: 37),
  User(firstName: 'Max', lastName: 'Stone', age: 27),
  User(firstName: 'Sarah', lastName: 'Winter', age: 20),
  User(firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Summer', age: 21),
  User(firstName: 'Lorita', lastName: 'Wilcher', age: 18),
  User(firstName: 'Anton', lastName: 'Wilbur', age: 32),

];
```

my user class that retrieves all the data above is:

```
class User {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final int age;

  const User({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.age,
  });

  User copy({
    String? firstName,
    String? lastName,
    int? age,
  }) =>
      User(
        firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
        age: age ?? this.age,
      );

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is User &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          firstName == other.firstName &&
          lastName == other.lastName &&
          age == other.age;

  @override
  int get hashCode => firstName.hashCode ^ lastName.hashCode ^ age.hashCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to extracting the data from excel, then I suggest that you look at:

https://pub.dev/packages/spreadsheet_decoder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    return DataTable(
        columns: const <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              'First Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              'Last Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              'Age',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        rows: allUsers
            .map(
              (user) => DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text(user.firstName)),
                  DataCell(Text(user.lastName)),
                  DataCell(Text(user.age.toString())),
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList());
       }
```

Full Project:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final allUsers = <User>[
    User(firstName: 'Emma', lastName: 'Field', age: 37),
    User(firstName: 'Max', lastName: 'Stone', age: 27),
    User(firstName: 'Sarah', lastName: 'Winter', age: 20),
    User(firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Summer', age: 21),
    User(firstName: 'Lorita', lastName: 'Wilcher', age: 18),
    User(firstName: 'Anton', lastName: 'Wilbur', age: 32),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DataTable(
            columns: const <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              'First Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              'Last Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(
              'Age',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ],
            rows: allUsers
                .map(
                  (user) => DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      DataCell(Text(user.firstName)),
                      DataCell(Text(user.lastName)),
                      DataCell(Text(user.age.toString())),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                .toList()));
  }
}

class User {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final int age;

  const User({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.age,
  });

  User copy({
    String? firstName,
    String? lastName,
    int? age,
  }) =>
      User(
        firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
        age: age ?? this.age,
      );

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is User &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          firstName == other.firstName &&
          lastName == other.lastName &&
          age == other.age;

  @override
  int get hashCode => firstName.hashCode ^ lastName.hashCode ^ age.hashCode;
}
```